# Grafana dashboard fails to load if one of the datasources of --mixed-- type is down

Tags: datasource, prometheus, grafana, dashboard, grafana-api

I am using **grafana 6.2.5** version. I created a dashboard with **ryantxu-ajax-panel** plugin and **--mixed--** datasource with five targets. The dashboard doesn't load if any of the **prometheus** query fails (like 503 service unavailable). I wanted to handle this error scenario and load the dashboard with the data coming from **other targets** without being blocked by any query failure. In console I see **'panel request cancelled'** which is coming from metrics_panel_ctrl feature file of grafana app.

Is there a way to fix this issue by handling the error in the module.ts file of ryantxu-ajax-panel plugin? Please suggest me with possible cases. Thanks